# Randomly shuffling a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

A similar question I saw on Stack Overflow dealt with a dict of lists (was a bad title), and when I tried using `random.shuffle` on my list of dicts per that answer, it made the whole object a None-type object.

I have a list of dictionaries kind of like this:

```
[
{'a':'1211', 'b':'1111121','c':'23423'},
{'a':'101', 'b':'2319','c':'03431'},
{'a':'3472', 'b':'38297','c':'13048132'}
]
```

I want to randomly shuffle like this.

```
[
{'a':'3472', 'b':'38297','c':'13048132'},
{'a':'1211', 'b':'1111121','c':'23423'},
{'a':'101', 'b':'2319','c':'03431'}   
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `random.shuffle` should work. Not sure why it's giving you a None-type object.

Comment: If you want to randomly shuffle the elements of a list, independently of what they are, just use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Otherwise define what you mean by randomly shuffle. Note that `random.shuffle` **modified** the original list. Use it as: `my_list = [...]; random.shuffle(my_list); print(my_list)`

Comment: `random.shuffle` shuffles the list in place and returns `None`.  You are probably doing `x = random.shuffle(x)` when you should be doing `random.shuffle(x)` without assignment.

Comment: See @StevenRumbalski's response!

Comment: You are absolutely right all of you :) Please don't downvote, nothing in the python docs specifies that it returns a NoneType object, genuine silly error I think others would benefit from knowing about.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati:  Interesting.  The docs online say "Shuffle the sequence x in place."  They say nothing about the return type, but it is a convention in Python that mutating methods and functions return `None`.   Oddly enough if you type  `help(random.shuffle)` in the interpreter you get "shuffle list x in place; return None."

Answer (score 13):

`random.shuffle` should work. The reason I think you *thought* it was giving you a None-type object is because you were doing something like

```
x = random.shuffle(...)
```

but `random.shuffle` doesn't return anything, it modifies the list *in place*:

```
x = [{'a':'3472', 'b':'38297','c':'13048132'},
     {'a':'1211', 'b':'1111121','c':'23423'},
     {'a':'101', 'b':'2319','c':'03431'}]
random.shuffle(x)  # No assignment
print(x)
```